# Flask failing to verify JWT signature for protected routes

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I am trying to "secure" my app login with JWT tokens, but it seems that I am encoding or decoding it wrong.  Why does it say I have an invalid signature, although JWT.io says it is valid?

I am setting up the secret key in my app initialization, and using it to encode and decode the JWT tokens:

```
#skey = os.urandom(16)
#app.secret_key = f"{skey}"
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abe535ed6a554fe48e09e111dad2dcbc' #temporary for testing
app.debug = True
print(app.secret_key)
```

I am protecting the `dash` route with this function:

```
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = request.args.get('token') #http://localhost:5000/route?token={jwttoken}
        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing'}), 403
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(token, app.secret_key)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token expired, log in again'}), 403
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid token. Please log in again.'}), 403
        
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

And here is the dash route:

```
@app.route('/dash', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@token_required
def dash():
    if 'logged_in' in session:
        if session['logged_in']:
            username = session['username']
            return render_template("dash.html", username=username)
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

When logging in with correct details, my login route redirects to dash with token as an argument:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        uname = request.form["uname"]
        pswd = request.form["pswd"]
        valid = auth.login(uname, pswd)
        if valid[0]:
            if valid[1]:
                session['username'] = uname
                session['logged_in'] = True
                token = jwt.encode({
                    'user' : uname,
                    'exp' : datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
                }, 
                app.secret_key)
                return redirect(url_for('dash', token=token))
            else:
               return redirect(url_for('login')) 
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return render_template("login.html")
```

But when I log in successfully, it redirects to dash, but ALWAYS says that I have an Invalid token, although I have verified it on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io):
[image][image]

Comment: Surprisingly I don't see any error on looking... Did it work before? Did you try clearing the cache in your browser and try again?

Comment: I tried on multiple browsers, clearing cache and using incognito mode, but I still get the same error

Comment: Now I remember, I faced similar issue while I first implemented JWT Tokens. Added the workaround I done to get rid of the issue in answers.

Comment: Try printing token and secret key right before decoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the algorithm while decoding the token.

```
data = jwt.decode(token, app.secret_key, algorithms=["HS256"])
```

Try this it will work

Comment: It indeed worked.  Thank you.  Why is that part necessary though, I thought HS256 was the default decoding algorithm?

Comment: no while encoding HS256 is default algorithm but while decoding we need to specify the algorithm

Comment: 'It is required that you pass in a value for the "algorithms" argument when calling decode().'
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: It is required that you pass in a value for the "algorithms" argument when calling decode().

it is the exception that is raised when we donot specify the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

An HTML page can only be in one encoding. The encoding could be different while creating the token. UTF-8 can support many languages and can accommodate pages and forms.

When you create the token add `.decode('utf-8')`:

```
token = jwt.encode({
                    'user' : uname,
                    'exp' : datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
                }, 
                app.secret_key).decode('utf-8')
```

Please note that the decode here is not from jwt library. It is just used to encode the string to UTF-8.

Comment: I get this error when adding the decode: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: It didn't work on PyJWT latest versions. Please downgrade your PyJWT module to version 1.7.1. It should work.

Comment: Latest pre-release 2.0.0a1 brings change of function jwt.encode, that doesn't return bytes as in release 1.7.1, but str.